# Description of a long exact sequence for $RP^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

For a sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ we have an associated long exact sequence in homology
$$\cdots\to H_n(X;A)\to H_n(X;B)\to H_n(X;C)\to H_{n-1}(X;A)\to \cdots.$$ The question asks to "describe this long exact sequence for $X=RP^n$ and the SES
$$0\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to 0"$$
(where the second map is multiplication by $2$).

I know that $H_i(RP^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)=\mathbb{Z}/2$ for all $0\leq i\leq n$ and $0$ otherwise and that $H_i(RP^n;\mathbb{Z})$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ for $i=0$, $i=n$ odd, $\mathbb{Z}/2$ for $0<i<n$ odd and $0$ otherwise. I don't know what is meant by "describe". Surely it doesn't mean to just write the values of the different homologies in the below sequence for $n$ odd and for $n$ even ? ie

$$H_{n+1}(RP^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H_n(RP^n;\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(RP^n;\mathbb{Z})\to H_n(RP^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to\cdots H_0(RP^n;\mathbb{Z})\to H_0(RP^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)$$
would be
$$0\to 0\to 0\to\mathbb{Z}/2\to\cdots\to\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2$$
for $n$ even and a different sequence written in a similar way for $n$ odd ? I just want to know what is asked/how the question above is to be interpreted (it is written exactly as I quoted it). Thanks.

Comment: I think it is asking what the map induced on homologies is. You have an SES of abelian groups $0\to \mathbf{Z}\to \mathbf{Z}\to \mathbf{Z}/2\to 0$. Then tensoring it with $C_*(X)$ gives an SES of chain complexes
$0\to C_*(X)\to C_*(X)\to C_*(X)\otimes \mathbf{Z}/2\to 0$. Then using the description of the LES you should be able to describe the map on homologies. The main problem is describing the connecting map because you are lifting $\mathbf{Z}/2$ coefficients to $\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't the SES just $0\to C_*(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{id\circ m_2}C_*(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{id\circ r_2}C_*(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to0$ where $m_2$ is multiplication by $2$ and $r_2$ reduces integers mod $2$ ?

Comment: I understand you are saying I should describe $C_*(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to C_{*-1}(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}$ where the first component of the map (the one on $C_*(X)$ is $\partial$. So take for instance $n$ even; part of the sequence is $H_n(RP^n;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H_{n-1}(RP^n;\mathbb{Z})$ ie $\mathbb{Z}/2\to \mathbb{Z}/2$; I'm still not sure how to proceed in describing $C_n(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\partial\circ?}C_{n-1}(X)\otimes\mathbb{Z}$.